# new 16.04 install doesnt recognize network devices

Tags: networking, ubuntu-drivers, additional-drivers

just built a server with S2600WT2 motherboard
i installed ubuntu 16.04 but no ethernet cards are recognized
i looked in the boards drivers and the only network Linux drivers are for redhat or suse
so what are my options? i have a fast approaching deadline to get the server live

Output of `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A2`  (obviously copied from screen, may contain errors):

```
subsystem: intel corporation c610/x99 series chipset smbus controller [8006:35e4]
kernel modules : 12c_1001
03:00.p ethernet controller [0200]: intel corporation 1350 gigabit network communication [8086:1521] (rev 01)
devive name intel 1350
subsystem: intel corporation 1q350 gigabit network connection [80086:35c4]
kernel driver in use: igb
kernel modules: igb
03;00.0 ethernet controller [0200]: intel corporation 1350 gigabit network conection [8006:1521] (rev 1)
subsystem ; intel corporation 1350 gigabit network connection [8086:35c4]
kernel driver in use ; igb
```

ip link

```
1: io: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc nocueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default glen 1
link/loopback 00;00;00:00:00:00 brd 00:00;00:00;00;00
2 eno1; <VROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 98:4f;ee:10:09:2d brd ff:ff:ff;ff;ff:ff
3: emp3s0f3 <BRIOASCCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdiscnoop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 98:4f:ee:10:09:2e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff;ff
```

ip a

```
1 io <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOEWN group qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00;00:00;00:00 brd  00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host io
valid_ift forever preferred_ift forevrer
inet6 : ;1/128 scope host
valid_ift forever prtefered_ift forevrer
2: eno1q <BROADCAST.MULTICASTT> MTU 1500 QDISC NOOP STATE down GROUP DEFAULT QLREN 1000
LINK/ETHER 98:4F:EE:10:09:2E BRD FF:FF:FF:FF;FF;FF;
3; EMP3S0F3; <broadcast,multicast> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 98;4f:ee:10:09:2e brd ff:ff;ff:ff;ff;ff
```

forgive typos till i can ssh  they both share the same screen so cant see what i'm typing only reading

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A2` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: added the info appreciate the fast reply

Comment: That suggests that the card is present and using the 'igb' module.  What's the output of `ip link` and `ip a` ?

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) (includes `lspci` and `ip` output) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Comment: that seems to be for wireless and i cannot connect to anything at this point

Comment: BTW, welcome to AskUbuntu!  Please use the formatting buttons (e.g. {} for code) or use markup (4 spaces after a newline for code), particularly when including code in your question or answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and suggest either:

1. your network cable or connector is faulty or not working; or
2. your network card has not been set to automatically raise the connection when the module loads (or the line is triggered); or
3. A BIOS setting for your network card is incorrect in relation to the expected operation in the module

Two adapters have been detected by your kernel and modules have been loaded to manage them.  They are called:

- eno1
- enp3s0f3

It's possible that these are actually the same adapter.  (e.g. I have servers here that emulate and appear as multiple network cards on the same physical interface.)

See [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) for how adapters are named in current kernels.

The outputs of both `ip link` and `ip a` show that the state is "DOWN".  **This *usually* means that the cable is not physically connected.**  So I would test your cables and the devices it's connecting to first.  Maybe plug the same cable into another laptop that you know works.

If/when you have discounted it being a cable/hardware fault, you might consider attempting to **force** the link up (overriding the trigger) like this:

```
ip link set eno1 up
```

Then, you can manually assign it an ip address like this:

```
ip addr add 192.168.0.5/24
```

(short form: `ip a a 192.168.0.5/24`)

(Obviously replacing the ip address and range with one relevant to your network.)

Then you can check to make sure it set correctly by calling `ip a` again and make sure that the state is "UP" and the IP is correct.

Then attempt to ping a device on the network. (Making sure that the device you're pinging has ICMP Echo Reply on - many have it switched off by default these days!)

If it works, then the module for your ethernet card doesn't yet know how to do line detection yet.  This is highly unusual, and I'd probably consider patching your kernel or getting a newer kernel ASAP if it does.

You may also be a victim of module blacklisting.  If the wrong module is being loaded for your network device (because the right one is blacklisted) you may have to edit /etc/modules.conf or the files in /etc/modules.conf.d/ to ensure that the right module loads and/or the wrong one is prevented from loading.

Finally, there may be a bug in the module for your card or a setting in your BIOS (particularly on newer rackmount servers) that control how the network card operates.

I've listed these in the order of decreasing likelihood.  YMMV.